# Calling a function in Structured text, Codesys 2.3

Tags: codesys, st

I'm new to Codesys, and PLC programming in general. I am currently being self-taught with the help of some literature. Currently working a practice program. I made a function but when I try to call it I get and error 4051, 'Throttle_Timer' is no function.

Here is the function

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK Throttle_Timer
VAR_INPUT
    delayTimeMs:TIME;

END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
END_VAR
VAR

    Delay:TON;
END_VAR

Delay(IN:=TRUE, PT:=delayTimeMs);
IF NOT(Delay.Q) THEN
   RETURN;
END_IF
Delay(IN:=FALSE);
```

Here is where I am trying to call it.

```
PROGRAM PLC_PRG
VAR
    Delay: TON;
END_VAR


(*Pressing the Speed Up Button*)
WHILE speedUp =TRUE AND Throttle<99.51 DO;
Throttle:=Throttle+0.5;

(*function call*)
Throttle_Timer(T#500ms)

END_WHILE;
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why. I call the function by name and in parentheses give it the input parameter. Was hoping someone could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

In CODESYS what we usually call a function in other programming languages is a `FUNCTION`.

`FUNCTION_BLOCK` on the other hand is closer to a class in other languages. A `FUNCTION_BLOCK` has it's own state, and needs to be initialized with a local variable, for example in your case:

```pascal
PROGRAM PLC_PRG
VAR
    mytimer: Throttle_Timer; // define an object of type `Throttle_Timer` (and initialize it)
END_VAR

mytimer(delayTimeMs := T#500MS); // execute the object block
```

Like classes in other languages, `FUNCTION_BLOCK` can have both Methods and Properties.

If you want to read more, check the [documentation](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.17.0/en/_cds_obj_function_block/).